# Launching *.msi thanks to Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-installer

I've have been trying to launch other programs with admin account in C++ with Windows API. It works well for *.exe files but not with *.msi files. I tried using `msiexec.exe` which works well in PowerShell, but not from cmd and not from my program. Is there a way to fix this? I'm on Windows 10, compiling with MinGW 64bits, and here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t s[] = L" /i \"path/my_installer.msi\"";

    STARTUPINFOW su_info;
    ZeroMemory(&su_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    su_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    BOOL b = CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"user", L"localhost", L"password", 0, L"msiexec.exe", s,
                                     0, nullptr, nullptr, &su_info, &pi);

    if(!b)
        std::cout << "An error occured" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Have you tried with the correct `\\` in the path?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work.

Comment: So, do you get an error? If so, what error code does `GetLastError()` report?

Comment: My program doesn't report any error, but `msiexec` complains about potentially not installed package when running from my program or cmd, but not from PowerShell. I also tried running PowerShell with my program and make it run `msiexec`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to run `msi` file with `ShellExecuteEx`? Directly the `msi` file - Windows knows the necessary `exe`. `lpVerb` can be `"RunAs"` to run with elevated privileges.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `RunAs` asks the user for a password, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: At the end of the day PowerShell is just going to be using CreateProcess to start msiexec, so it must be possible for you to do the same. Maybe try Process Monitor to see exactly what arguments it's running it with, what the current directory is at the time, that sort of thing.

Comment: If your app is running in the logged-in users account, it only has the privileges that are available to that account, which is why `RunAs` prompts for the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the argument `L" /i \"path/my_installer.msi\""`. The arguments after `"/i"` option should not contains `/`.

The following path sample work for me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t s[] = L" /i \"C:\\Users\\username\\...\\my_installer.msi\"";

    STARTUPINFOW su_info;
    ZeroMemory(&su_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    su_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    BOOL b = CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"user", L"domain", L"password", 0, L"msiexec.exe", s,
        0, nullptr, nullptr, &su_info, &pi);

    if (!b)
        std::cout << "An error occured" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```